# Is there a BigQuery equivalent to numpy.digitize?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I try the code below but my query exceeded resource limits even after clustering over t2.min and t2.max

```
select t1.myint64, t2.myindex
from t1, t2
where t1.myint64 between t2.min  and t2.max
```

Here is t1 schema...

```
myint64            INTEGER        NULLABLE
```

... and what table t1 looks like:

```
myint64    
 464578733234443
 756557774664663
 315676667544877
 485675445434553
 864664656568335
       ...
 464676656756776
         8857667
 866867887876666
 974244466724434
1025895506842623

[5876218 rows x 1 columns]
```

Here is t2 schema ...

```
Field name    Type        Mode    
myindex        INTEGER        NULLABLE
min            INTEGER        NULLABLE    
max            INTEGER        NULLABLE
```

... and what table t2 looks like:

```
myindex               min                max
0                       0     70368744177663
1          70368744177664     87960930222079
2          87960930222080     96757023244287
3          96757023244288     97306779058175
4          97306779058176     97581656965119
...                   ...                ...
110544    919191720820736    923589767331839
110545    923589767331840    932385860354047
110546    932385860354048    949978046398463
110547    949978046398464    985162418487295
110548    985162418487296   1125899906842623

[110549 rows x 3 columns]
```

and the desired results is:

```
myindex               myint64
 14456        464578733234443
 34355        756557774664663
  6465        315676667544877
 15354        485675445434553
 41455        864664656568335
                          ...
 14476        464676656756776
     0                8857667
 83444        866867887876666
 93545        974244466724434
110548       1025895506842623

[5876218 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: How many columns do your tables have? Do you need to `select *`?  You might also try a `cross join`; i'm not sure of the exact execution of `left join on true`, but a `cross join` wouldn't need to evaluate a join clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me make the assumption that the `max` value is not really needed.  That is, you are looking for the first "min" value in `table2`.

Let me also assume that `table2` is not very large.

The following may look cumbersome, but it might do what you want:

```
select t1.*,
       (select min(minval)
        from unnest(t2.ar) minval
        where val >= minval
       ) as min
from table1 t1 cross join
     (select array_agg(t2.min order by min) as ar
      from table2 t2
     ) t2;
```

If this works, then you can join back to `table2` to get the minimum value.

Why might this work better?  Basically, BigQuery sees your query and decides that it has to send lots of data all over the place.  By converting `table2` to an array, only the array is sent to where the `table1` data resides.  The `unnest()` is then local to each record in `table1`.  In my experience, this can be a big win performance-wise.

EDIT:

Because you seem to be looking for one match, another method is to interleave the two tables, use cumulative window functions, and then filter:

```
with t as (
      select t1.myint64, null as t2min
      from t1
      union all
      select null, t2.min
      from t2
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, max(t2min) over (order by coalesce(t2min, myint64)) as real_t2min
      from t
     ) t
where t2min is null;
```

Once again, if you need the `max()` you can `join` back to `t2`.

Comment: Great suggestion, this answer work if t1 and t2 contain respectively 5M+ and 20k+ rows. This also work for t1 and t2 containing 100k+ and 100k+ rows respectively. However this doesn't work for t1 contains 5M+ rows and t2 contains  100k+ rows. Any other idea?

Comment: Could you please share the error message you are getting?

Comment: @EnriqueZetina Operation timed out after 6.0 hours. Consider reducing the amount of work performed by your operation so that it can complete within this limit.

Comment: @FrancoisB. . . . Did you try the second method in the answer?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just tried your second method in the answer and it's working! Thank you so much. I was looking for only one match per bin indeed... and the result comes really fast (less than 20 seconds). A lot more better than a join in my case! Thank you so much!